# Parameters at end of line, no value

Tags: neovim

When I have a program like this:

```c
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n"); format: // <-- this shows up, colored a bit darker than a comment

    return 0;
}
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Here's my config:

```
:set number
:set relativenumber
:set autoindent
:set tabstop=4
:set shiftwidth=4
:set smarttab
:set softtabstop=4
:set mouse=a

call plug#begin()

Plug 'sainnhe/everforest' " Everforest
Plug 'http://github.com/tpope/vim-surround' " Surrounding ysw)
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree' " NerdTree
Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline' " Status bar
Plug 'https://github.com/lifepillar/pgsql.vim' " PSQL Pluging needs :SQLSetType pgsql.vim
Plug 'https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color' " CSS Color Preview
Plug 'https://github.com/rafi/awesome-vim-colorschemes' " Retro Scheme
Plug 'https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim'  " Auto Completion
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons' " Developer Icons
Plug 'https://github.com/tc50cal/vim-terminal' " Vim Terminal
Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/tagbar' " Tagbar for code navigation
Plug 'https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors' " CTRL + N for multiple cursors
Plug 'https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs' " Auto closing
Plug 'https://github.com/wsdjeg/vim-assembly' " Assembly plugin
Plug 'glepnir/zephyr-nvim' " Zephyr theme

set encoding=UTF-8

call plug#end()

let NERDTreeCascadeOpenSingleChildDir=1

nnoremap <C-k> :Terminal bash
nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <C-l> :call CocActionAsync('jumpDefinition')<CR>

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="-"

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

:set completeopt-=preview " For No Previews

:colorscheme everforest

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" airline symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '¯é░'
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = '¯é▒'
let g:airline_right_sep = '¯é▓'
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = '¯é│'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '¯éá'
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = '¯éó'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¯éí'

inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "<Tab>"
```

EDIT: Here's a picture:[image: The picture]

Comment: some kind of coc extension?

Comment: Can you move your cursor to these text or they are some kind of 'virtual' text? Do you still have the text if you disable the `coc` extension?

Comment: Yes, Coc extenstion, No, I don't have it if i disable it. Its virtual text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking at Coc InlayHint.
You can disable inlay hint by making sure the following line is part of your Coc Configuration:

```
    "inlayHint.enable": false,
```

The easiest way to change your Coc configuration is to run the command:

```
:CocConfig
```

It let you edit the `~/AppData/local/nvim/coc-settings.json` on Windows and `~/.Config/nvim/coc-settings.json` on Linux.

If you start with an empty configuration you should make sure it is a valid `.json` file by having the opening and closing curly bracket:

```
{
    "inlayHint.enable": false,
}
```